# Terminal stalling on every command due to Xcodebuild

Tags: xcode, terminal, xcodebuild, iterm2, iterm

I just updated Xcode to 11.4 and suddenly my terminal (iTerm 3.3.9) is now very slow. Typing a command works fine, but upon pressing enter I often wait 3-4 seconds to perform a simple task (`cd`, `git add`, etc).

When I look at the status bar I notice that `xcodebuild` is running during the time while I am waiting. I'm assuming that the new Xcode update did something that makes this process longer or needs a setting updated somewhere.

I have already tried `sudo xcodebuild -license accept` and that did not fix the problem. Additionally, there is no `xcodebuild` call inside of my `.zshrc` file.

Where can I find out what the terminal is trying to do with Xcodebuild? I suspect identifying the command being run is the first step towards determining how to fix it.

FWIW, this problem also happens in the Apple-provided terminal, so I don't think it's iTerm specific.

Comment: This is going to sound really stupid but did you restart the computer? I find that that is crucial after updating Xcode, or everything bogs down.

Comment: I haven't, but I will try now and report back

Comment: try running top -o cpu. I'm not seeing any changes.

Comment: @johnelemans that shows iTerm at the top pretty consistently. Idling around 20% of CPU when I've got nothing running except `top`. Restarting didn't work unfortunately :(

Comment: that's a bad sign. but I'm not seeing it in Terminal either. running Xcode, 50 safari pages etc.

Comment: Hmmm. That's definitely not a good sign haha. Guess i'll hunt around to see if I can find anything else. Thank you both!

Comment: Do you have nvm installed ?

Answer (score 1):

I've found many answers but at the first start the console is still very slow (15s).

At end looking around I found out that somehow it's `nvm` that needs `xcodebuild`.

The slowdown was fixed changing the `nvm` default to `system`

```
nvm alias default system
```