# Terminal slow to start first time due to xcodebuild

Tags: xcode, macos, terminal, xcodebuild, macos-big-sur

The first time I run Terminal or start SmartGit either one is slow to start, taking up to ~30 seconds. When I look at the status bar for Terminal I see that it is stuck running some `xcodebuild` command. Not sure what exactly the command is.

Does anyone know how to view which commands Terminal runs on startup? Or if anyone else had this issue? I think it is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60872495/terminal-stalling-on-every-command-due-to-xcodebuild) but the slow down is only first the first startup of Terminal and for ~30 seconds. Not the 2-3 seconds users reported. Subsequent runs or commands work normally.

Comment: I switched from Bash to Zsh and the problem went away. I guess something was in the bash config causing the slowdown but still don't know what.

Comment: im having this problem too, since i switched to bigsur

Comment: d= (-_- ) Same here, don't dive up! - running `xcodebuild -find clang` takes 43 seconds before echoing: `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang` (I will switch to static path till Apple fixes that)

Comment: Solution, if you are the developer of the tool (like I was) simply use `/usr/bin/xcode-select -p` output as path-prefix, instead of full-path using `xcodebuild` tool (which takes less than one second).

Answer (score 36):

Switch Apple Git to Git, the problem will go away.
Run `brew install git` to do it.
Relate link:
https://blog.smittytone.net/2021/05/21/how-to-fix-xcodebuild-macos-terminal-slow-downs/

Another option is to accept the Xcode License

```
sudo xcodebuild -license accept
```

You can find this referring to the reference in the linked article.

Comment: I accepted the xcodebuild license and I'm using brew version of git but the issue is still present

Comment: Same here; I accepted the license, using homebrew git, still slow starting terminal first time after reboot.

Comment: This doesn't work.

Answer (score 13):

I've tried with `sudo xcodebuild -license accept` but at start the console is still very slow and, after a reboot, I have to wait at least 15s to see the terminal.

Looking around I found out that somehow it's `nvm` that needs `xcodebuild`.

The slowdown was fixed changing the `nvm` default to `system`

```
nvm alias default system
```

Comment: What is `system` defined as? I do not have that alias.

Comment: @DhananjaySuresh try with `nvm list` and see

Comment: I do not have `system`. My `default` is `node` (16.13.0)

Comment: +100 for finding nvm needs xcode

Comment: Thanks for relating to nvm. I have added an answer that references a workaround from an nvm github issue that avoids changing the nvm default alias.

Comment: For me, `nvm` was the real issue in terminal as well as VSCode. I moved to https://mise.jdx.dev/

Comment: @freedev can you please share how you managed to find this? Would be a great lesson ! Thank you

Comment: @CiprianTomoiagă I had a look at process monitoring to see what was consuming resources (CPU/disk) while I was waiting for the shell prompt...

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
sudo xcode-select --install
sudo xcode-select -switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

https://ospfranco.com/post/2021/08/05/fix-slow-terminal-start-(hanging-xcodebuild)/

Comment: Thanks StefanoF. All above not work but this work for me.

Comment: This is the one. Given that my XCode was reinstalled recently only the last `switch` command was necessary.

Answer (score 6):

#### Try `xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch`

Then after it is complete, open up **2** new Terminal tabs.

Worked for me on macOS 12.6.

I found this solution over here: https://superuser.com/a/1742463/98148

Answer (score 4):

### context:

I used some of the other answers here, but they didn't actually fix it for me, as initially I didn't realize it only is slow for the first startup **per restart**. Following on the comment relating the problem to `nvm`, I came across an [nvm GitHub issue regarding this problem](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/issues/2747). Their [solution](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/issues/2747#issuecomment-1045703075) which works for me across restarts is:

> OK! So it appears adding this line to ~/.zshrc above the nvm lines works around the problem for now:

```
alias manpath=false
```

### solution (workaround):

Add the `alias manpath=false` line before sourcing `nvm.sh` in `~/.zshrc`:

```
alias manpath=false
export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh
```

Now restart (or however you wish to trigger the `~/.zshrc` file being resourced).

### notes:

This agrees with the fact that it happens per restart, i.e., per `~/.zshrc` execution. Also, for me I also have a non-system default for nvm, which corresponds to [freedev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70886502/3897838), but I need a v19+ default node version for isomorphic webcrypto, so that answer isn't acceptable.

You can read through the nvm GitHub issue for a more in depth analysis. I would recommend giving the issue a thumbs up, because the rep from nvm seemed to be incredulous that it was not a localized issue to that issue's OP. But this question has been upvoted 35 times, which clearly shows this is not the case.

Comment: This was the solution for me using GNU Bash 5.2.26 without changing my NVM default.