# xcodebuild runs very slow on macOS Server

Tags: xcodebuild

On our mac ci server `xcodebuild` has started to run extremely slow.

When I google 'xcodebuild slow' I find a lot of questions/answers about xcodebuild slowing down the terminal ([link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65846945/terminal-slow-to-start-first-time-due-to-xcodebuild), [link2](https://ospfranco.com/post/2021/08/05/fix-slow-terminal-start-(hanging-xcodebuild)/)) which is not at all my problem:
When I ssh onto the Server, it perfectly smoothly has zsh run everything in a responsive way.

I noticed the issue when our iOS ci builds started timing out:
However we have to run our builds through XCode via fastlane - But no matter what xcodebuild command I run (even `xcodebuild -version`) is slow to the point of broken - it will output

> Xcode 13.2.1
> Build version 13C100

immidiately, but then the process does not exit and block the terminal io for minutes or even hours (its not consistent)

This used to just work fine for the last year and most part of January.
Why could be the issue here?